# сменяемые баннеры

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы баннеры сменяли друг друга

Comment: Баннеры — ваши собственные картинки/ссылки, или какая-то баннерная сеть?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем изобретать велосипеды? Давно всё написано.

Надо несколько прокручивающихся баннеров? - Карусель, как пример, [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), мне лично она очень нравиться. 
Если надо только один, сменяющий другой, то в сети тысячи слайдеров, [вот один из них](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/)

Все они очень легко настраиваются и модернизируются по нуждам разработчика.

Comment: Весомый вариант.

Answer (score 1):

[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) мой любимый вариант для решения баннерных задач.
[фоторама](http://fotoramajs.com) тоже очень интересное решение

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то задачи такого рода надо описывать подробнее.

Через php на страницу выводите баннеры. Загоняете их в массив javascript. Один делаете видимый, остальные невидимы. И далее по средствам javascript через интервалы веремени setInterval() делаете невидимым текущий банер и проявляете следующий.